# how to orderby() count without group in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Users table which has `under_reference` column that represents by whom this user was referred.

I want to order user by having highest `under_reference` count. How to order by counting under reference

```
$data['user'] = User::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Post your migrations class also

Comment: change column type **varchar** into **integer**

Comment: no because under_reference has usersname of referr

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz i think your answer is correct but problem is in my view blade

Comment: `@php $i = 0;@endphp
        @foreach($user as $p)
            @php $i++;@endphp

            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->amount}} - {{ $basic->currency }}</td>
                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($p->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['user'] = User::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->groupBy('under_reference')
  ->orderBy('under_reference','DESC')
  ->get();
```

Here is the query that can help you. You can get the total users referred by a person and orderBy reference.

Comment: @waqar SHOW  the data in screenshot from phpmyadmin

Comment: You forgot to add the `under_reference` in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By for this situation, and sort from it. Here's an example.

```
$query = [
        'name',
        'email',
        // store count of under_reference as total
        DB::raw('count(under_reference) as total')
    ];

$sorted = User::groupBy('name', 'email')
        ->select($query)
        ->orderBy('total', 'desc') // remember total before, sort it by desc or asc
        ->get();
```

You can refer from laravel documentation [here on raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions)

The `name` and `email` is just an examaple, as you didn't show us what your table's column looks like. But you should get a pretty rough idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way also worked.

```
$data['user'] = DB::select('SELECT *` FROM `user` ORDER BY 
CAST(`under_reference` AS decimal) DESC');
```

You can cast the DB column varchar to decimal in query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user_info = DB::table('users')
->select('under_reference',DB::raw('count(under_reference) as ur'))
->groupBy('under_reference')
->orderBy('ur','DESC')
->get();
```

Comment: OP wants to order by *having highest under_reference count*, not the actual `under_reference` column.

Answer (score 0):

i created another column totalref with Integer . i coded logic to update this column also with referral bonus and then orderby totalref. and it worked like magic